# `--prefix=/`,`--program-prefix=g` and `--without-gmp` mean

Tags: coreutils, configure

When I install the coreutils, I found that

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.30 --program-prefix=g --without-gmp
```

What does the `--prefix=/`, `--program-prefix=g` and `--without-gmp` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options to `configure` are explained in the output of `configure --help`, but the coreutils source distribution also has good documentation in its `INSTALL` text file.

In short, `--prefix` sets the installation prefix.  This is the top directory under which `bin`, `lib` and other directories will be installed.  The default installation prefix is often `/usr/local`, but it's common to want to install software elsewhere, which is why this `--prefix` option exists.

The Homebrew package manager for macOS, which you seem to be using, uses `--prefix` to install the GNU coreutils under a particular path and gives access to them by means of symbolic links and the option to modify your `PATH` environment variable. Homebrew is designed to not install stuff directly under `/usr/local` which allows you to use that installation path for things that you compile and install yourself.  See [the Homebrew FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#can-i-install-my-own-stuff-to-usrlocal) for information and caveats about this.

With `--program-prefix` one can set a string that should be prepended to all executable binaries.  It is very common to prefix the GNU coreutils executables and the executables of other GNU software with a `g` on non-Linux Unices that already provide native utilities with the same names. This means that you'll get `gls`, `gxargs`, `gnice` etc. as the names of the binary executables.

The `--without-gmp` disables the use of `gmp` which is a GNU library for arbitrary precision arithmetics.

The options are common to all software that comes with a `configure` script generated by [`autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html).  The common form of the last option is `--without-xxx` where `xxx` is some other library that one would want to avoid using (or *want* to use, with `--with-xxx`).  There are often additionally `--disable-xxx` and `--enable-xxx` options for disabling and enabling specific program features.